# Sencha Touch 2: Auto-update panel with setRecord() when record changes?

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch-2

With Sencha Touch 2, is there a way to auto-update panel with setRecord() when the record changes?

Help is much appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: sure, you can auto update Panel on record changes , can u post your code sample..

Comment: code is pretty simple: I do panel.setRecord(record); I have a store that auto syncs. I do record.set(name, value); I find the record is updated but panel still shows the old record value. I tried doing a setRecord() on the panel again, but the value wouldn't change. Thoughts?

Comment: So it looks like it actually does auto update, but when displaying a field with 'convert' using tpl on the panel, the panel does not auto update. Is this expected? Any thoughts?

Comment: so, you think panel is auto-updating...But your panel contains `tpl` , which didn't update..right ?

Comment: No, I mean panel is updating and tpl works, but only with non-converted fields of the model. A field that has convert in the model definition does not update in tpl.

Comment: what you mean by `non-converted` fileds..

Comment: Like a model's fields that are not: `{
                name: 'fullName',
                type: 'string',
                convert: function(value, record) {
                    return record.get('firstName') + ' ' + record.get('lastName');
                },
                persist: false
            }`

Comment: It's hacky, but if you set the internal data that is cached for your `convert` field to `undefined`, the model will refresh it with another call to your function.